# fail to create QFile (only with msvc2017 uwp)

Tags: c++, qt, uwp, qt5

Create a simple application qt5.12 , 5.13 compile it uwp mcvc 64 bit 2017

Trying to create the file :

```
bool ret;
FILE *fp = fopen ("Name","w+"); // this command return NULL
QFile file("Name");
Ret = file. open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

Also filed :

```
winrtrunner.app: QIODevice::write (QFile, "Name"): device not open
```

Comment: If you're using `Name` or any other non-absolute path: the file will be created in the current working directory, which might not be what you expect and might not be writable. Also check file.errorString() after the failed open().

Answer (score 1):

If `fopen ("Name","w+")` returns `NULL` then the file couldn't be opened. Hence you will almost *certainly* get an error when you open and try to write to it with the Qt stuff.

You need to find out *why* you couldn't open it. For a start, you should examine `errno` immediately after the failed `fopen`, or use `perror` to get more readable output:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("Name", "w+");
if (fp == NULL) perror("Could not open file: ");
```

---

Additionally, you can check the reason for the failed `QFile.open()` by using the (inherited) `QIODevice::errorString()`:

```
ret = file. open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
if (! ret) {
    const auto problem = file.errorString();
    // Now log problem somehow.
}
```

Comment: The  problem concerning to UWP it works ok in mingw

Comment: @itamarlevit: and what did the `perror` output when you ran it? That's a rather important peice of information, isn't it? :-)

Comment: The problem is access is Access is denied and it's because we try to work in UWP framework.